# How to plot points around a circle in R

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I am trying to plot some data on directions which vary from 0 to360 deg. The most intuitive way of doing this is around a circle where I can plot each point (I only have 13 points to plot).

```
cont=c(319,124,182,137,55,302,221,25,8,36,132,179,152)
```

My data for one plot

I tried following the ggplot2 guides and have not got it to work. I'm not very good at ggplot though...

(my dataframe is called "data")

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=1), ) + coord_polar(theta = "y") +geom_point(y=cont)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works adding y to the ggplot mapping

```
data <- data.frame(cont = cont)
ggplot(data, aes(x=1, y = cont)) + coord_polar(theta = "y") + geom_point()
```

You can add other ggplot parameters to improve the appearence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `polar.plot` from [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/) library?

Comment: specifically `plotrix::polar.plot(lengths=rep(1,length(cont)),polar.pos=cont,radial.lim=c(0,1.5))`

Comment: The function is designed for this kind of plots while ggplot2 is more general and has many other applications.